# Обрезка текста по предложениям

Tags: php

Данный код не корректно разбивает текст на предложения

---

```
//разбиваем на массив
$arr=explode(".",$row['text']);
//берем первые 6 элементов
$arr=array_slice($arr,0,6);
//превращаем в строку
$kratko=implode(".",$arr);
echo$kratko;
```

---

Если в предложении имеется несколько точек, например S.T.A.L.K.E.R то конечно выведется текст не корректно.
Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: нет, ты разбиваешь по точке, в слове S.T.A.L.K.E.R есть точки, и предложение не будет валидным, напиши регулярку и укажи там больше 5 символов А-я

Comment: Не очень то дружу с этими регулярками.

Comment: Д. Котеров PHP5 для профессионалов, ищешь главу с регулярками и учишь

Answer (score 2):

Есть очень сильное подозрение, что при любом уровне "продвинутости" вашей системы останется необходимость вычитки результатов.

Сначала вы разберетесь со случаями типа S.T.A.L.K.E.R., потом столкнетесь с [парцеллированными предложениями](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%E0%F0%F6%E5%EB%EB%FF%F6%E8%FF_(%F1%E8%ED%F2%E0%EA%F1%E8%F1)). решите учитывать регистр букв - споткнетесь о тексты, в которых первые слова в предложениях написаны с маленькой буквы (типа этого предложения)...

Есть еще и такие случаи исхода предложения: !, !!, !!!, ?, ?!, ?!!, ??!, ???, ..., !.., !!., ?.., ??., ?!. - это только то, что предполагается пунктуацией русского языка. Но много ли текстов вы видели, написанных по правилам? Кстати, как вы будете делить первое предложение в этом абзаце?

Если возможно автоматизировать черновую работу по делению текста на части, а потом вычитать его - сделайте так.

Comment: Согласен с @Khvorostin.  
@vitagame Для начала надо определиться с тем, что вы хотите получить на выходе, а потом уже искать решение.

Answer (score 1):

А что если резать не по предложениям, а по количеству символов или по определённому символу?..

```
function short($str, $count)
    {
     $sym = '#';
     $string_cut = wordwrap($str,$count,$sym);
     $result = explode($sym,$string_cut,2);
     return $result[0];
    }
    $text = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.# It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.';
    $short = short($text, 300);
    echo $short;
```

Данная функция обрежет текст когда найдёт символ #. Если она не найдёт в тексте такого символа, то обрежет всё, что после трёхсотого символа. Если знак # находится дальше трёхсотого символа, всё равно будет обрезано всё, что после трёхсотого.

Comment: Это тоже не выход.